# Concatenate multiple rows into one row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

From the dataframe which row contains one specific product,

```
data = [['Alpha', '#10','Apple','2020-10-01',4], 
        ['Alpha', '#10','Tomatoes','2020-10-15',1.5], 
        ['Beta', '#12','Banana', '2019-03-06', 2],
        ['Beta', '#14','Dragonfruit', '2020-04-05', 3],
        ['Charlie', '#16','Watermelon', '2019-01-02', 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['customer_name', 'order_number','product_variant','date','net_sales'])
```

I want to merge the rows so that one row contains one order number.
Expected df

```
data_expected = [['Alpha', '#10',np.NaN,'Apple','Tomatoes','2020-10-01','2020-10-15',5.5],
                 ['Beta', '#12','#14','Banana','Dragonfruit','2019-03-06','2020-04-05',5], 
                 ['Charlie', '#16',np.NaN,'Watermelon',np.NaN,'2019-01-02',np.NaN,5]]
df_expected = pd.DataFrame(data_expected, columns = ['customer_name','order_number_1', 'order_number_2','product_variant_1','product_variant_2','date_1','date_2','net_sales'])
```

In the real dataframe, one customer may have more than 2 products within the same order number,
and may have more than 2 order numbers, and more than 2 dates as well (as in the real world).

Comment: I advice against concatenating this data. It is in table format so it is easier to operate on it, than it will be when you concatenate it.
What do you need to do with these customer orders? Maybe solution to your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @pawmasz thank you for your feedback. I want to differentiate customer churns. It is much easier to do if one row pertains to one customer. Don't you agree?

Comment: You could just count it as churn = (number of distinct customers at end of month - number of distinct customers at end of previous month)/(number of distinct customers at end of previous month). I'll provide a code answer using your data frame in a bit.

Comment: I will give credit to David as he provided the answer, but you are very welcome to help as well, without the points though, for fairness to him. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can first create a `cc` column that takes the cumulative count
2. Then, use `.groupby` to calculate the sum of net sales, which you will add to the dataframe later.
3. `pivot` the dataframe and and rename the multi-index column as one column joining together with `_`. #pivot has a major bug in previous versions. You can upgrade with pip install pandas --upgrade
4. Create the new aggreagated `net_sales` column by setting to `s` -- the series you created earlier, prior to manipulating the shape of the dataframe.

---

```
df['cc'] = (df.groupby('customer_name').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
s = df.groupby('customer_name')['net_sales'].sum()
df = df.pivot(index=['customer_name'], columns='cc', values=['order_number','product_variant','date'])
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns]
df['net_sales'] = s
df

Out[1]: 
order_number_1 order_number_2 product_variant_1  \
customer_name                                                   
Alpha                    #10            #10             Apple   
Beta                     #12            #14            Banana   
Charlie                  #16            NaN        Watermelon   

              product_variant_2      date_1      date_2  net_sales  
customer_name                                                       
Alpha                  Tomatoes  2020-10-01  2020-10-15        5.5  
Beta                Dragonfruit  2019-03-06  2020-04-05        5.0  
Charlie                     NaN  2019-01-02         NaN        5.0
```

Comment: this is not my question, but this is a beautiful concise answer! :)

Comment: @SandervandenOord Thank you!

Comment: unfortunately, I got a  "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5345, 3), indices imply (1, 3)"

Comment: @Luc can you upgrade pandas to the latest version? `pivot` has a major bug in previous versions. You can do this with `pip install pandas --upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate an excellent accepted answer exists, but here is my 'one-liner'

```
df2 = df.groupby('customer_name').apply(lambda x:pd.DataFrame(x.reset_index().unstack()).transpose())
df2
```

gives you this

```
|                | ('customer_name', 0)   | ('customer_name', 1)   | ('date', 0)   | ('date', 1)   |   ('index', 0) |   ('index', 1) |   ('net_sales', 0) |   ('net_sales', 1) | ('order_number', 0)   | ('order_number', 1)   | ('product_variant', 0)   | ('product_variant', 1)   |
|:---------------|:-----------------------|:-----------------------|:--------------|:--------------|---------------:|---------------:|-------------------:|-------------------:|:----------------------|:----------------------|:-------------------------|:-------------------------|
| ('Alpha', 0)   | Alpha                  | Alpha                  | 2020-10-01    | 2020-10-15    |              0 |              1 |                  4 |                1.5 | #10                   | #10                   | Apple                    | Tomatoes                 |
| ('Beta', 0)    | Beta                   | Beta                   | 2019-03-06    | 2020-04-05    |              2 |              3 |                  2 |                3   | #12                   | #14                   | Banana                   | Dragonfruit              |
| ('Charlie', 0) | Charlie                | nan                    | 2019-01-02    | nan           |              4 |            nan |                  5 |              nan   | #16                   | nan                   | Watermelon               | nan                      |
```

which is almost as required except for some aggregation and cleanup, along the lines of

```
del df2['customer_name']
del df2['index']
df2['net_sales_total'] = df2['net_sales'].sum(axis=1)
del df2['net_sales']
df2.columns = [c[0] + '_' + str(c[1]) for c in df2.columns]
df2.rename(columns={'net_sales_total_':'net_sales'}, inplace=True)
```

so we get

```
|                | date_0     | date_1     | order_number_0   | order_number_1   | product_variant_0   | product_variant_1   |   net_sales |
|:---------------|:-----------|:-----------|:-----------------|:-----------------|:--------------------|:--------------------|------------:|
| ('Alpha', 0)   | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-15 | #10              | #10              | Apple               | Tomatoes            |         5.5 |
| ('Beta', 0)    | 2019-03-06 | 2020-04-05 | #12              | #14              | Banana              | Dragonfruit         |         5   |
| ('Charlie', 0) | 2019-01-02 | nan        | #16              | nan              | Watermelon          | nan                 |         5   |
```